# Fetch single record using recordName and it should return specific field from icloud

Tags: objective-c, cloudkit

I want to fetch single record from icloud using cloudkit.

here is the code which I am using:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordName contains %@",recordId];                                       
NSLog(@"predicate------%@",predicate);
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"AmuzItems" predicate:predicate];
CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
queryOperation.database = publicDatabase;
queryOperation.resultsLimit =1 ;
queryOperation.desiredKeys = @[@"name",@"city",@"state"];
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord * record) {
        NSLog(@"record------%@",record);
};
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor * cursor, NSError * operationError) {
    if (operationError) {                                                                                              NSLog(@"error--------%@",operationError);                                                                                                                                            
 } else
    {
        NSLog(@"cursor------%@",cursor);
    }
};
```

want to retrieve `name, city, state` fields only. There are 15 fields in RecordType.code doesn't return anything,not even error.

Comment: Can you try setting the queryOperation.qualityOfService to .UserInteractive

Comment: @EdwinVermeer :Thanks for reply.I tried it but it doesn't work.after that i used NSOperationQueue. and make some change in nspredicate and it work.

Comment: ah... I missed that one. You forgot the [queryOperation start]; as the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who face same problem like me:

```
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordID == %@",[[CKRecordID alloc]initWithRecordName:recordId]];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"RecordTypeName" predicate:predicate];
CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
NSOperationQueue * operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queryOperation.database = publicDatabase;
queryOperation.resultsLimit =1 ;
queryOperation.desiredKeys = @[@"name",@"city",@"state"];
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord * record) {
 NSLog(@"record------%@",record);
};
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor * cursor, NSError * error) {
    if (error) {
          NSLog(@"error--------%@",error);            
    } else
    {
        if (cursor) {
            NSLog(@"cursor-------%@",cursor);
        }
        else
        {
                NSLog(@"end");
        }
    }
};
 [operationQueue addOperation:queryOperation];
```

Comment: You don't need a NSOperationQueue. Instead what you forgot is to execute the start on the queryOperation.

Comment: yes.[queryOperation start] also works.but what's difference between "queryoperation start" and NSOperationQueue..because both are working here in same manner.

Comment: a queue is a container that could handle multiple operations. There is already a queue available in the database. Instead you could also call         publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit would be of performing the .start or using addOperation on the database. I see that most sample code use the addOperation.